# With multiple monitors, can I pick which one an application will load on?

Tags: spaces, display

In Spaces it's possible to specify which space a given application will open on -- for example, my web browser always opens on Space 1 and iTunes on Space 3.  Is something similar possible with multiple monitors, so that whichever space I'm on a certain application will always open on the second monitor?  For even more control, can I specify that it will always open on Monitor 2 of Space 4?

Comment: If you move an application to a different monitor, won't it remember that location and be there the next time you launch it? That's pretty much how it works on my setup.

Comment: It seems to depend on the application.  Terminal does remember, X-Windows doesn't, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Not with the default Apple Spaces.

There is an alternative, though. CocoaBots makes a small app called Hyperspaces which builds upon the default Spaces and adds a bunch of cool features. Multi-monitor support is coming to their next release.

http://thecocoabots.com/blog/post/148/hyperspaces-104-and-the-road-to-11/

Answer (score 1):

[Stay App](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) sounds like it might do what you want.

> If you’re fastidious about keeping
>   your windows tidy, Stay is for you.
>   Stay ensures that your windows are
>   always where you want them to be, even
>   as you connect and disconnect
>   displays.